# Ruby- How to covert a string into an operator

Tags: ruby

I have a program that takes a string as a parameter, but the user also enters in what operator they want to perform.  They enter in the operator as a string and I need to convert it to an actual operator that would work.  What is the best way to convert "+" to + so that it can be used as an operator?

Answer (score 4):

use `public_send`. send is more dangerous, because it lets you also call private methods.

```
3.public_send("+", 5) # => 8
3.public_send("system", "rm *.txt") # => NoMethodError: private method `system' called for 3:Fixnum
```

You can check if the user has given a valid method by calling `respond_to?`

```
3.respond_to?("+")      # => true
3.respond_to?("sinus")  # => false
```

Better is that you white list the allowed operators

```
allowed = ["+", "*", "-", "/", "^", "modulo",]
if allowed.include? given_operator
  num.public_send(given_operator, arg1)
else
  puts "invalid operator given"
enU
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `send`.

```
3.send("+", 5) # => 8
```

Comment: why send and not public_send? what diff?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has messages instead of methods, so you can do this:

```
1.send('+', 2) # => 3
```

Comment: duplicate answer